# jupyterhub installed with docker image failed login with error in spawning new server

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I have a Linux server, am running jupyterhub docker image following this doc,
https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/quickstart-docker.html

I couldn't find default username and password.(jupyterhub/jupyter didn't work for me).

I did ssh into container and added user - (cmd - adduser veerpati)
[image]

When i login with this user, its failing to spawn server.

**My use case:** I need to launch server for multiple users( using docker spawner - https://jupyterhub-dockerspawner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/spawner-types.html#dockerspawner)
[image]